# Groupin Clients when client is new in year ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have list of invoices. I wonna group data into sales_departments but only this clients who have first invoice in 2018 Year.

Below my "data". Sory for mystake but i can't paste data better.

```
Client_Number    sales_depart   Netto   Number_Invoice  Invoice_Date
1022562          0140           113     51545121188     04.11.18
1022562          0140           139     5586258568      04.01.18
1022564          0140           171     5586713889      03.22.18
1022565          0140           211     5587169210      03.22.17
1022566          0140           259     5587624531      03.22.16
1022567          0140           319     5588079852      03.23.15
1022568          0140           392     5588535173      03.23.14
1022569          0140           483     5588990494      03.23.13
1022570          0140           594     5589445815      03.23.12
1022571          0140           730     5589901136      03.24.11
1008144          0530           898     5590356457      01.31.18
1008145          0530           104     5590811778      02.20.18
1008146          0530           358     5591267099      02.20.17
1008147          0530           671     5591722420      02.21.16
1008148          0530           055     5592177741      02.21.15
1008149          0530           528     5592633062      02.21.14
1008150          0530           109     5593088383      02.21.13
1016058          0130           825     5593543704      01.18.18
1051643          0290           704     5593999025      01.30.18
1051643          0290           175     5595199025      01.30.17
1049433          0180           786     5594454346      02.20.18
1010219          0180           117     5594909667      02.28.18
1033233          0180           754     5595364988      02.28.18
1004914          0160           767     5595820309      02.14.18
1011699          0140           244     5596275630      02.20.18
1007323          0160           290     5596730951      04.19.18
1004914          0160           036     5597186272      02.07.18
1005837          0530           645     5597641593      04.19.18
```

The data I would like to receive

```
Sales Dept Count_Clintr
0130       1
0160       2
0180       3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a single table scan using the `HAVING` clause:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c435cc/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Client_Number, sales_depart, Netto, Number_Invoice, Invoice_Date ) AS
SELECT 1022562, '0140', 113, 51545121188, DATE '2018-04-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022562, '0140', 139, 5586258568, DATE '2018-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022564, '0140', 171, 5586713889, DATE '2018-03-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022565, '0140', 211, 5587169210, DATE '2017-03-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022566, '0140', 259, 5587624531, DATE '2016-03-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022567, '0140', 319, 5588079852, DATE '2015-03-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022568, '0140', 392, 5588535173, DATE '2014-03-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022569, '0140', 483, 5588990494, DATE '2013-03-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022570, '0140', 594, 5589445815, DATE '2012-03-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022571, '0140', 730, 5589901136, DATE '2011-03-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1008144, '0530', 898, 5590356457, DATE '2018-01-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1008145, '0530', 104, 5590811778, DATE '2018-02-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1008146, '0530', 358, 5591267099, DATE '2017-02-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1008147, '0530', 671, 5591722420, DATE '2016-02-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1008148, '0530', 055, 5592177741, DATE '2015-02-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1008149, '0530', 528, 5592633062, DATE '2014-02-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1008150, '0530', 109, 5593088383, DATE '2013-02-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1016058, '0130', 825, 5593543704, DATE '2018-01-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1051643, '0290', 704, 5593999025, DATE '2018-01-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1051643, '0290', 175, 5595199025, DATE '2017-01-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1049433, '0180', 786, 5594454346, DATE '2018-02-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1010219, '0180', 117, 5594909667, DATE '2018-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1033233, '0180', 754, 5595364988, DATE '2018-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1004914, '0160', 767, 5595820309, DATE '2018-02-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1011699, '0140', 244, 5596275630, DATE '2018-02-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1007323, '0160', 290, 5596730951, DATE '2018-04-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1004914, '0160', 036, 5597186272, DATE '2018-02-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1005837, '0530', 645, 5597641593, DATE '2018-04-19' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT sales_depart,
       COUNT( client_number )
FROM   (
  SELECT sales_depart,
         client_number
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY
         sales_depart,
         client_number 
  HAVING MIN( Invoice_date ) >= DATE '2018-01-01'
)
GROUP BY sales_depart
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c435cc/2/0)**:

```
| SALES_DEPART | COUNT(CLIENT_NUMBER) |
|--------------|----------------------|
|         0140 |                    3 |
|         0530 |                    3 |
|         0180 |                    3 |
|         0130 |                    1 |
|         0160 |                    2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `not exists` for filtering:

```
select sales_department, sum(netto)
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.client = t.client and
                        t2.invoice_date < date '2018-01-01'
                 )
group by sales_department;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(client, invoice_date)`.  Also not the use of the `date` keyword to define the constant using ISO/ANSI standard formats.

Comment: Thank's  for the anwer the solution is good but how I can close the solution i for example I Q  first invoice Between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-31' ?

Comment: @Błażej . . . I don't really understand the comment.  Your question is specific to the year 2018.  If you want an invoice during a particular time period, use `exists` with similar logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
SELECT sales_depart, COUNT(Distinct client_Number) AS Distinct_Clients
FROM Table1
GROUP BY sales_depart
HAVING MIN(TO_DATE(invoice_date, 'MM.DD.YY')) >= TO_DATE('01-01-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
ORDER BY sales_depart
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
SALES_DEPART    DISTINCT_CLIENTS
0130                1
0160                2
0180                3
```

**Note:** Since, `Client_Number = 1004914` repeats 2 times in `Sales_depart = 0160` so it is counted 1 time only.

Link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/28c71/1

Comment: @Błażej Try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sd.sales_depart,COUNT(sd.Client_Number) AS Client_Number
FROM sales_departments sd
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT sales_depart,MIN(Invoice_Date) AS Invoice_Date
FROM sales_departments
WHERE Invoice_date >= DATE '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY sales_depart
) T
ON T.sales_depart=sd.sales_depart
GROUP BY sd.sales_depart
```